# haskell fail to import Data.List module

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

```
  |
4 |   import Data.List.Split
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


--  While building package myproj-0.1.0.0 using:

    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I got this error, how can i import the module to haskell file?
I got this error when compile in vs code or when debugging

Second error in file after compile with stack build, i already added Split in cabal build depends

```
Cabal file 

Building all executables for `myproj' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
myproj> configure (exe)
Warning: myproj.cabal:21:10: Tabs used as indentation at 21:10
Configuring myproj-0.1.0.0...
myproj> build (exe)
Preprocessing executable 'myproj' for myproj-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'myproj' for myproj-0.1.0.0..

<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out in which package the module is included.

https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Data.List.Split

So you need the [`split` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split). Put in the `build-depends` of your `myproj.cabal` file (or `package.yaml`, if you use `hpack` or `stack`)

```
   split >=0.2 && <0.3
```

(the version bounds are optional, but it's recommended to fix the x.y when in doubt)

Then, at next build, `cabal` or `stack` will pull in the required dependencies and thus make the module available.

Comment: Thankyou so much! But i got error                                                                                        `<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated `
because there is no Main module.   Is this mean because I dont have Main module? and also if i dont use stack or cabal, can i still compile the file directly without specify the split.package?

Comment: You could theoretically download all needed modules manually from Hackage, but why would you? It's just cumbersome and a maintenance nightmare. — So, that error comes from... vs code? Surely it calls stack under the hood, can you show the raw commands for reproducability?

Comment: I added the error after i executed stack build, do you know how can i fix this? and also when i try to compile the code in terminal without use stack or debug using vscode, i got module split error, do you mean i have to install manually the module to computer?

Comment: and also when i compile the code using ghci then :l name of file, it load the module with no error , what is the different with using stack to build?

Comment: Yeah, that just means it works now. The error you get now is because you're trying to build the module as an executable, but for that it would need to be called `Main` and contain a `main` action.